# Using Rainmeter with Python

Tags: python, user-interface, integration, rainmeter

So I have designed a layout in Rainmeter which serves as a GUI for my Voice Assistant program. Now, I want to integrate the running of Rainmeter with Python. For example, if an user already has a Rainmeter layout loaded in his/her system, then running my script will automatically override his/her layout and activate my Layout unless he/she manually changes it back to his/her own layout. This process would continue whenever my script is run. It basically goes like this: The user runs the script, it checks whether any other skin is loaded or not **(Assuming that Rainmeter is installed on the system)**. If any other skin is loaded, it overrides the skin with my one else it bypasses the override function and directly loads my skin.

I have no idea on how to achieve this thing. I have successfully written the lines to start and exit rainmeter with python but I don't know anything about how to load the layouts! Please help!

Here is the script I have written to start and exit Rainmeter:

```
import os
trigger = input()

if trigger == "y":
    try:
        os.startfile("C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe")
        print("Rainmeter started successfully")
    except:
        print("There was an error")

trigger = input()

if trigger == "exit":
    try:
        os.system("taskkill /f /im Rainmeter.exe")
        print("Rainmeter closed successfully")
    except:
        print("There was an error")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to load a Rainmeter Layout:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe", "!LoadLayout", "abcd"])
```

Here we are using rainmeter [bangs](https://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/bangs/) to load the layout. Change `abcd` with name of your layout.